# Number of subsets with given sum and length

Tags: elementary-set-theory

From a competition archive:

> How many 7-subsets of $\{1,2,3,\dots,14\}$ are there, such that the sum of all the numbers in the subset is a multiple of 14?

The given answer is 246, which I have confirmed with some programming.

However, **where does the answer come from? Less importantly, is there a general formula for this?**

Some other questions I've read:

> [Number of ways to add up to a number without repetition (order does not matter)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/766526/number-of-ways-to-add-up-to-a-number-without-repetition-order-does-not-matter)
> [Number of ways to write a number $N$ as the sum of $M$ natural numbers, where order doesn't matter?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2720772/number-of-ways-to-write-a-number-n-as-the-sum-of-m-natural-numbers-where-or)
> [How many ways can a natural number n be expressed as a sum of one or more positive integers, taking order into account?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1907123/how-many-ways-can-a-natural-number-n-be-expressed-as-a-sum-of-one-or-more-positi)

However, none of these have the answer that I want. I suspect there must be a neat trick using modulos or something. I've tried, but I can't quite figure it out.

Comment: Generating function is the way to go in the general problem.  Also, surely you mean $7$-subsets rather than subsets having this mysterious property called "length"?

Comment: @user10354138 all my life I thought subsets have lengths haha... Yeah, I meant 7-subsets

Answer (score 1):

Take the generating function
$$
G(x,y)=\prod_{n=1}^{14}(1+x^ny)
$$
where $y$ is handing out a tag for "we select this number" and the $x$ is keeping track of the sum, so the coefficient of $x^ky^\ell$ is counting $\ell$-subsets that sum to $k$.  Then extracting multiples of 14 from $x$ is easy --- just average over what you get from setting $x$ to be a $14$-th root of unity, and extract $y^7$-coefficient for $7$-subsets.  In other words, just calculate
\begin{align*}
&[y^7]\frac1{14}\sum_{j=0}^{13}\prod_{n=1}^{14}(1+\zeta_{14}^{nj}y)\\
&=[y^7]\frac1{14}\sum_{j=0}^{13}\prod_{n=1}^{14/\gcd(14,j)}(1+\zeta_{14/\gcd(14,j)}^ny)^{\gcd(14,j)}\\
&=[y^7]\frac1{14}\sum_{d\mid 14}\phi(d)(1-(-y)^d)^{14/d}\tag{**}\\
&=\frac1{14}\sum_{d\mid 14}\phi(d)\underbrace{[y^7](1+(-1)^{d+1}y^d)^{14/d}}_{\neq 0\text{ only when }d\mid 7}\\
&=\frac1{14}\sum_{d\mid 14\text{ and }d\mid 7}\phi(d)[y^7](1+(-1)^{d+1}y^d)^{14/d}\\
&=\frac1{14}\sum_{d\mid 7}\phi(d)[y^7](1+(-1)^{d+1}y^d)^{14/d}\\
&=\frac1{14}\left(\phi(7)\binom{2}{1}+\phi(1)\binom{14}7\right)\\
&=246.
\end{align*}
where in (**) we collect the $j$s according to $d=14/\gcd(14,j)$ and use $\prod_{n=1}^d(1+\zeta_d^n y)=1-(-y)^d$.

Comment: Let me tell you, I'd have no idea what you're talking about had I not watched [this 3B1B video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bOXCLR3Wric) (lucky me!). I'll take the time to try digesting your answer. Thank you